# PHP Convert string response to an Array from an API

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the  following value which is returned via API  :

```
[{"message":"No transactions found"}]
```

this information comes back as a string and I  would like to convert it to a JSON or an array. 
I have the following two options  :

```
 $decoded_msg = json_decode($mpesa_offline_status,TRUE);

                    echo $decoded_msg['message'];
```

which return a warning message : `Message: Illegal string offset 'message'` and this option also:

```
  $decoded_msg = json_decode($mpesa_offline_status,TRUE);

                    echo $decoded_msg->message;
```

and I get the following error :

```
Message: Trying to get property 'message' of non-object
```

how can I approach this?

Comment: var_dump($decoded_msg) to see what you get and you will know howto access the property

Comment: I get the  following :   string(37) "[{"message":"No transactions found"}]"

Comment: Is this your exact code? Because there's no way `json_decode($mpesa_offline_status,TRUE);` would produce that string.

Comment: This is how the  $mpesa_offline_status looks like :   "[{\"message\":\"No transactions found\"}]"

Comment: now  u have multiple ansswers, try them

Comment: Try accessing it as an object; `echo $decoded_msg->message;`

Comment: your question is still open, are you still searching for solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of `messages`, so you cannot access 'message' at the top level.

```
$mpesa_offline_status = '[{"message":"No transactions found"}]';
$decoded_msg = json_decode($mpesa_offline_status, true);

var_dump($decoded_msg[0]['message']);
```

you have to access a valid index. Same with that:

```
$mpesa_offline_status = '[{"message":"No transactions found"}]';
$decoded_msg = json_decode($mpesa_offline_status, false);

var_dump($decoded_msg[0]->message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Having `[]` with this API response means, when you use [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) this will generate a multi dimensional array, here `[]` will be converted into `0` index and `message` will be associated with `0` index something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [message] => No transactions found
        )
)
```

For this if you want to access `message` index which inside the `0` index, you can access as like:

```
<?
$string = '[{"message":"No transactions found"}]';
$decode = json_decode($string,true);
echo $decode[0]['message']; // No transactions found
?>
```

**Side Note:**

`Message: Illegal string offset 'message'` error doesn't mean, to switch on to property instead of array, this message means, you are trying to access a string value which is an array.